# HAProxy stats socket - incorrect values

Tags: haproxy

One of my HAProxy monitoring script isn't working on a newly setup HAProxy box. I've tracked down the issue to the output of the stats socket rather than with the script itself.

I'm getting values of "0" being reported via the socket, but the correct values from the webinterface.

Can anyone explain the differences in the output?

---

From the output of `echo 'show stat' | nc -U /var/run/haproxy.socket`:

```
pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,check_status,check_code,check_duration,hrsp_1xx,hrsp_2xx,hrsp_3xx,hrsp_4xx,hrsp_5xx,hrsp_other,hanafail,req_rate,req_rate_max,req_tot,cli_abrt,srv_abrt,
haproxystats,FRONTEND,,,0,0,4096,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,1,0,,,,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,,
haproxystats,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,4096,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,0,0,0,,0,155,0,,1,1,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,
vip1,FRONTEND,,,0,0,4096,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,,
webservers,web1,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,155,0,,1,3,1,,0,,2,0,,0,L7OK,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web2,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,155,0,,1,3,2,,0,,2,0,,0,L7OK,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web3,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,155,0,,1,3,3,,0,,2,0,,0,L7OK,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web4,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,155,0,,1,3,4,,0,,2,0,,0,L7OK,200,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web5,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,155,0,,1,3,5,,0,,2,0,,0,L7OK,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web6,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,155,0,,1,3,6,,0,,2,0,,0,L7OK,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,6,6,0,,0,155,0,,1,3,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,
```

CSV output of webinterface from the same server:

```
pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,check_status,check_code,check_duration,hrsp_1xx,hrsp_2xx,hrsp_3xx,hrsp_4xx,hrsp_5xx,hrsp_other,hanafail,req_rate,req_rate_max,req_tot,cli_abrt,srv_abrt,
haproxystats,FRONTEND,,,1,2,4096,309,186616,3323540,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,1,0,,,,0,1,0,4,,,,0,225,0,0,83,0,,1,4,309,,,
haproxystats,BACKEND,0,0,0,1,4096,83,186616,3323540,0,0,,83,0,0,0,UP,0,0,0,,0,231,0,,1,1,0,,0,,1,1,,2,,,,0,0,0,0,83,0,,,,,0,0,
vip1,FRONTEND,,,6,11,4096,20,45181,1069426,0,0,0,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,0,0,7,,,,0,69,3,4,0,0,,0,30,76,,,
webservers,web1,0,0,0,2,,13,7445,243262,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,231,0,,1,3,1,,13,,2,0,,5,L7OK,200,1,0,12,1,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web2,0,0,0,1,,13,7445,127627,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,231,0,,1,3,2,,13,,2,0,,5,L7OK,200,0,0,12,0,1,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web3,0,0,0,1,,13,7570,81039,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,231,0,,1,3,3,,13,,2,0,,5,L7OK,200,0,0,13,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web4,0,0,0,1,,13,8053,182209,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,231,0,,1,3,4,,13,,2,0,,5,L7OK,200,1,0,11,1,1,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web5,0,0,0,2,,12,7288,230933,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,231,0,,1,3,5,,12,,2,0,,5,L7OK,200,1,0,11,0,1,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,web6,0,0,0,1,,12,7380,204356,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,231,0,,1,3,6,,12,,2,0,,5,L7OK,200,1,0,10,1,1,0,0,0,,,,0,0,
webservers,BACKEND,0,0,0,6,0,76,45181,1069426,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,6,6,0,,0,231,0,,1,3,0,,76,,1,0,,30,,,,0,69,3,4,0,0,,,,,0,0,
```

---

Version information:

```
[root@haproxy ~]# haproxy -v
HA-Proxy version 1.4.19 2012/01/07
```

Relevant config exert:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local0 debug
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.socket
```

Permissions:

```
[root@haproxy ~]# ls -lah /var/run/haproxy.socket
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Mar  9 14:13 /var/run/haproxy.socket
```

Comment: Could be a bug.  Have you reported this to HAProxy's author?